# How to create roles in parse.com

Tags: ios, roles, parse-platform

I'm on ios and in the process of designing a new app with parse.com as back-end. 
I have read the documentation on Roles so I have a good idea on how to create them in code.

But to me it seems strange to have some code in your app that's only going to be run once, as I only have to create the 3 roles that I want once. 
Is there another way to create roles other than with code in my app? 
It doesn't seem like it's possible with the databrowser to do it manually. 
Have I misunderstod something completely? Or should I just create the roles via the ios app and delete the code afterwards?

PS.: The 3 roles i need are; customer, retailer, admin.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the REST interface to create / configure these details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to create the Roles, you should be able create them in the Data Browser web interface.

If you don't have a "Role" class in your Parse app yet, you can add it by clicking the "New Class" button under your Classes list and choosing the "Role" type.